# AS3: Textfield active state

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I would like to create some text on the stage that *does not* respond to mouse activity.  I've found that after adding a piece of text to a class I am using to draw, it covers up some of the mousing area of my class and disables the user from being able to roll over the other graphical elements...

Is there something like:

```
var t:TextField = new TextField();
t.text = "hello";
t.active = false;  //i know that this is wrong, but I haven't found an equivalent method
```

Thanks,
jml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
t.selectable = false;
```

Comment: Thanks, sam.  Don't know how I had missed that.

Comment: FWIW, the problem also had to do with the order in which I was adding children.  Because the textfield has "on top", it was obstructing the mousing area of the other graphics.  A quick fix for this (don't know of any other way) is to add the child textfield so that it draws 'below' the other stuff.